# recipe for target 'broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb' failed

Tags: raspberry-pi4, android-kernel, android-automotive

I am trying to build an Android Automotive OS for Rpi 4b image following [this post by Snapp Automotive](https://medium.com/snapp-automotive/android-automotive-os-11-on-a-raspberry-pi-2abaa133f468)

When I try to build the RPi kernel, running

```
ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- DTC_FLAGS=”-@” make broadcom/bcm27
11-rpi-4-b.dtb
```

throws the following error.

```
        Input formats are:
                dts - device tree source text
                dtb - device tree blob
                fs  - /proc/device-tree style directory
  -o, --out <arg>            
        Output file
  -O, --out-format <arg>     
        Output formats are:
                dts - device tree source text
                dtb - device tree blob
                asm - assembler source
  -V, --out-version <arg>    
        Blob version to produce, defaults to 17 (for dtb and asm output)
  -d, --out-dependency <arg> 
        Output dependency file
  -R, --reserve <arg>        
        Make space for <number> reserve map entries (for dtb and asm output)
  -S, --space <arg>          
        Make the blob at least <bytes> long (extra space)
  -p, --pad <arg>            
        Add padding to the blob of <bytes> long (extra space)
  -a, --align <arg>          
        Make the blob align to the <bytes> (extra space)
  -b, --boot-cpu <arg>       
        Set the physical boot cpu
  -f, --force                
        Try to produce output even if the input tree has errors
  -i, --include <arg>        
        Add a path to search for include files
  -s, --sort                 
        Sort nodes and properties before outputting (useful for comparing trees)
  -H, --phandle <arg>        
        Valid phandle formats are:
                legacy - "linux,phandle" properties only
                epapr  - "phandle" properties only
                both   - Both "linux,phandle" and "phandle" properties
  -W, --warning <arg>        
        Enable/disable warnings (prefix with "no-")
  -E, --error <arg>          
        Enable/disable errors (prefix with "no-")
  -@, --symbols              
        Enable generation of symbols
  -A, --auto-alias           
        Enable auto-alias of labels
  -T, --annotate             
        Annotate output .dts with input source file and line (-T -T for more details)
  -h, --help                 
        Print this help and exit
  -v, --version              
        Print version and exit
Error: missing files
scripts/Makefile.lib:286: recipe for target 'arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb] Error 1
Makefile:1347: recipe for target 'broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb' failed
make: *** [broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb] Error 2
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not getting the ASCII quotation marks ("), but instead you've got a unicode one. Try re-typing the "'s in the command.